# which Instance Mode would be better for wcf service for Online game application?

Tags: wpf, wcf

I have created one game application which will be played by players across the internet. I current using wcf services as web services for this game.
which Instance would be better for wcf service for Online game application?

Comment: That most likely depends on the requirements of your game/service. We'd need a lot more detail to make any useful judgement!

Comment: Thanks Dan,As my game shares common data amongst multiple clients.

Comment: How do you store that data, though? If it's in a database then it probably doesn't matter what you use. If it's in memory then you want a single instance. Is it low latency, or can you accommodate some lag? Etc...

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends. If you're writing the code from the ground up, it's relatively arbitrary.  In general, I think it makes sense to lean towards Per Instance, because shared state is often better stored elsewhere than the service implementation.

One way to achieve shared state is to have a singleton instance of that game state.  That way, each WCF service call just references that singleton. This provides some separation of concerns: The service implementation deals with communication and keeping the game in sync happens elsewhere.